# generating test report using html test runner in sikuli

Tags: sikuli

I have read that we can generate test reports in sikuli using HTML test runner.

I have installed SIKULI X and have script for which I want to generate reports.

Is there any particular version of html test runner I need to install for this version of Sikuli ?

I have downloaded the "html-testRunner-1.0.3.tar.gz (md5)" from the path "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html-testRunner".

Can anyone guide me on how I should install and integrate the same to my script ?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I downloaded `HTMLTestRunner.py` from [this website](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html) and put somewhere in my computer. Say if I put it in `~/Downloads/HTMLTestRunner` folder, I just need to tell my sikulix program to find the path into that folder, and import HTMLTestRunner afterwards. This part is as follows:

```
import sys
_path = r"Downloads/HTMLTestRunner"
sys.path.append(_path)
import HTMLTestRunner
```

After that, everything goes as usual. Lemme try to make one example below.

```
import unittest
import sys
_path = r"Downloads/HTMLTestRunner"
sys.path.append(_path)
import HTMLTestRunner

class TestDemo(unittest.TestCase):
    def testA(self):
        assert True
    def testB(self):
        assert False

class TestDemo2(unittest.TestCase):
    def testC(self):
        assert True
    def testD(self):
        assert True

def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    # TestDemo
    suite.addTest(TestDemo('testA'))
    suite.addTest(TestDemo('testB'))
    # TestDemo2
    suite.addTest(TestDemo2('testC'))
    suite.addTest(TestDemo2('testD'))

    return suite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = suite()
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
    output = open("results.html", 'w')
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=output, title='Test Report', description='This is a test')
    runner.run(suite)
```

When you run it, you will get the following report
[image: HTMLTestRunner report]

Hope it helps